Are $0$-definable sets a countable model of ZF
Above proposition sounds surprising. Can someone check for the mistake?
Let me call a formula unary, if it has exactly one free parameter and a set $\emptyset$-definable, if membership is given by a unary formula ($m=\{x| \varphi(x)\}:=[\varphi]$).
Lemma: If $\varphi(v_0,v_1,..,v_n)$ is a formula of set theory, then for each assignment  $ v_1,.. v_n$ with $\emptyset$-definable sets $[\psi_1],...,[\psi_n]$ there is a unary formula $\psi$ such that $\psi(x)=\varphi(x,[\psi_1],...,[\psi_n])$
(see Is any formula, whose parameters can be defined by unary formulas, equivalent to a unary formula?
Proposition:For every model M of ZF the set $D^M$ of $\emptyset$-definable sets is a countable model of ZF.
Proof:
Ext and Foundation are given by M. For the other axioms we need to prove, that the desired set is $\emptyset$-definable. We will use $x:=[\varphi]$ and apply the lemma to the below given formulas.
Pairing: $\{x,y\}=[v_0 = x \lor v_0=y]$ with $y=[\psi]$
Union: $\bigcup x = [\exists z : (v_0 \in z) \land \varphi(z)])$
Power: $\mathcal{P}(x) = [v_0 \subseteq x]$
Inf: $\omega=[\forall z : \big(\emptyset \in z \land \forall u : \big( (u \in z) \rightarrow (u \cup \{u\}) \in z \big) \, \big) \rightarrow v_0 \in z]$
Separation: For $\psi(v_0,v_1,...v_n)$ let the equivalent unary formula be $\tilde{\psi}(v_0)$. Then $[\tilde{\psi}(v_0) \land \varphi(v_0)]$ is the desired set.
Replacement: Let $\psi(u,v,p)$ be the functional with domain $x=[\varphi], p=[\theta]$
then $y =[\exists u: \exists w: \varphi(u) \land \psi(u, v_0, w) \land \forall v_a: v_a \in w \leftrightarrow \theta(v_a)]$ is the desired set.

I don't see why you chose the word 'o-definability.' I was confused with the o-minimality in model theory that is completely irrelevant to your question.

I don't see any immediate error from your argument, but you should be careful that your notion of o-minimality is not expressible internally in $M$. (It does not affect your argument, though.)

Many thks. 0-def is zero, not o (but it look like here) and I chose it, because these formulas at the end ripple down to the empty set (which is the ordinal number 0).

@AscanHeydorn The standard notation for this is "$\emptyset$-definable" (even "$0$-definable" would read better - if you use math mode, the $0$ is distinguishable from O and o). I've taken the liberty of adjusting this.

There's lots of problems here. Even Extensionality will not necessarily hold. For instance after adding a "Cohen real" to $L$, the set of real numbers and the set of constructible reals are different sets, but they contain the same $\emptyset$-definable real numbers. That's why we usually use "hereditarily" definable to get a model of ZF.

@Jonathan Then there must be a mistake in the proof. Can you enlight me? Why does Extensionality not hold? All $\emptyset$-definable sets are sets in the ground model and there extensionality holds.

@AscanHeydorn Why should Extensionality in $M$ imply that it holds for any substructure of $M$? Try to write down that argument carefully and see where it fails.

@AscanHeydorn The next problem is with Separation. You have to interpret the formula $\psi$ in the model $D^M$ and not in $M$ to really obtain the set of elements of $[\varphi]$ statisfying $\psi$ in $D^M$ (because that's what Separation actually says). Same for Replacement.
